# Android: How can i set Tags for images in Gridview?

Tags: android

Hi can anyone tell me How can I set And get the tags for the images which are in GridView.
Thank You in advance mates.
i've written the following code but it does not work? Is this Right?

```
int jj=100;
    for(int j=0;j<ia.imageid.length;i++)
        {

        g.getChildAt(j).setTag(jj);
        jj++;
        }
```

Comment: are you aware of the methods `setTag()` and `getTag()`? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the adapter's `getView`..

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View view;
   if(convertView == null) {
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, null);
   }
   else
      view = convertView;

   ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
   image.setTag();
}
```